NavigationStack with .navigationDestination doesn't works for me
I'm new with SwiftUI and I have a problem with the navigation with NavigationStack and .navigationDestination(). When I press the button with the label: Ir a binding View, the navigation doesn't occur. This is my code:
//
//  StateView.swift
//  SWiftUITutorial
//
//  Created by Ismael Márquez on 10/4/24.
//

import SwiftUI

class UserData: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var name = "Ismael Márquez"
    @Published var age = 22
}

struct StateView: View {
    
    @State private var value = 0
    @State private var selection: Int?
    @State private var readyToNavigate = false
    @StateObject private var user = UserData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("El valor actual es \(value)")
                Button("Suma 1") {
                    value += 1
                }
                Text("Mi nombre es \(user.name) y mi edad es \(user.age)")
                Button("Actualizar datos") {
                    user.name = "Pedro"
                    user.age = 33
                }
                Button {
                    //Code here before changing the bool value
                    readyToNavigate = true
                } label: {
                    Text("Ir a BindingView")
                }
            }
            }.navigationTitle("StateView")
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
                    BindingView(value: $value, user: user)
                }
        }
}

#Preview {
    StateView().environmentObject(UserData())
}


Previously I managed to do navigation with Navigation view and navigationLink but that method is deprecated in iOS 16.

Submit a bug report there are several posts on SO boit this same issue

navigationDestination should modify the VStack, not NavigationStack.

Put the .navigationDestination() in the NavigationStack:
NavigationStack {
    VStack {
        Text("El valor actual es \(value)")
        Button("Suma 1") {
            value += 1
        }
        Text("Mi nombre es \(user.name) y mi edad es \(user.age)")
        Button("Actualizar datos") {
            user.name = "Pedro"
            user.age = 33
        }
        Button {
            //Code here before changing the bool value
            readyToNavigate = true
        } label: {
            Text("Ir a BindingView")
        }
    }.navigationDestination(isPresented: $readyToNavigate) {
        BindingView(value: $value, user: user)
    }
}.navigationTitle("StateView")


I realize this isn't your exact problem but since I got here via google trying to solve the same thing, wanted to post in case someone else runs into the same problem I had. In my case, attaching the .navigationDestination to an if/else block didn't work consistently. I had to encapsulate everything into a Group and pin the .navigationDestination on the group, like this:
NavigationStack(path: $path) {
   Group {
      if homes.count < 1 {
         ...
      } else {
         ...
      }
    }
    .navigationDestination(for: NavigationItem.self) { item in ...

